# Rendering a partial list view and partial form within a details view

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So I am tryng to create a comment form and a comment view within a post view.

Basically i have a post view from my blog, and i want to show a comments form and a comment section on each.

I have the views all prepared, and so far i have my form displayed at the bottom of my post view.

What i am looking to do is add my comments view to the post view above the form.

**Comment Controller**

```
// GET: /Comments/_AllComments - Partial view
public ViewResult _AllComments(int postid)
{
     TempData["PostId"] = postid;
     return View("_AllComments");
}
```

**Post Detail View**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Post

//MARKUP  OMITTED

//Comments Partial View
@Html.Partial("_AllComments", new Invest.Models.Comment())

//Comments Form Partial View
@Html.Partial("_Comment_Form", new Invest.Models.Comment())
```

**Partial View - All Comments**

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Comment>

//MARKUP OMITTED
```

The error that i get is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.Comment', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyProject.Models.Comment]'.

Could someone tell me how I get round this?. I have tried  changing the partial to `Html.RenderPartial` which didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely you will see that your *partial view needs a **collection*** and you are passing *a **single** object*.

To solve this you can change the line with partial to like below:

```
//Comments Partial View
@Html.Partial("_AllComments", new List<Invest.Models.Comment>(){ new Invest.Models.Comment()})
```

**Note:** Using `Html.Partial` won't make a call to Action `_AllComments`, if you want to use the result of that action (the partial view), `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` are used to do that.

Comment: Hi Adricadar, thank you for your help. I have added these things and now get another issue.
**{"The controller for path '/Post/Details/4' was not found or does not implement IController."}**  This is the very view that these partial views sit on. Not sure what this is

Comment: if i remove this line:
             **@Html.Action("_AllComments", "Comments", new List<MyProject.Models.Comment>() { new MyProject.Models.Comment() })**

It works fine but of course does not show the partial view.

Comment: @AndyMc you don't use Html.Action in the same way as Html.Partial, please read the signature of the method first and you can search for examples to use it, there are plenty of them.